# Django ManyToMany relationship

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin, many-to-many

In **models.py**:

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils.translation import ugettext as _

# Create your models here.
class Category(models.Model):
    name            = models.CharField(_(u"Name"), max_length=250)
    products        = models.ManyToManyField("Product", verbose_name=_(u"Products"), \
                      blank=True, null=True, related_name="+")
        
class Product(models.Model):
    name            = models.CharField(_(u"Name"), max_length=250)    
    category        = models.ManyToManyField("Category", verbose_name=_(u"Category"), \
                      blank=True, null=True, related_name="+")
```

In admin page:

[image: m2m relationships]

The question:
How can the relations between `products` and `category` m2m fields in **models.py** be set so that in admin-page, as it can be seen at the picture, `b2`(the product) was marked as it belongs to `a2` (the category).
Any advices for implementation of [products, categories] are welcomed, thank you.


P.S.
I'm newbie in Django. Sorry for my English.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that you have *two* ManyToMany fields. As you've noted, when the relationship is set in one of them, it isn't in the other.

The solution is simple: drop one of the fields. You only need a ManyToManyField on one side of the relationship. Django gives you access to the other side automatically. So, if you kept the  `categories` field on the `Product` model, you can do `my_product.categories.all()` to get the categories a product is associated with; and `my_category.product_set.all()` to get the products that belong to a category.

You'll also need to drop the `related_name="+"` attribute: you've presumably put that in because you were getting conflicts, which should have been a clue.

Comment: Also further reading can be found from Django docs https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#many-to-many-relationships

Comment: If one m2m field is left (e.g. in class `Product` the `category`), how can i set that the related product\s belong to category from `Home>>Catalog>>Categories` if there's no fields to choose from?
I mean: i need to choose a category/ies when creating an product and choose product/s (that would belong to that category) when creating a category.
Thank You.

Comment: I still do not get how can i apply category to products if there's no ManyToManyField (or other field to access at all). Simply talking if i can do: `my_product.category = some_category` how can i make `my_category.product = some_product`?

Comment: As I noted in my response, there is a field on the reverse relationship: `product_set`. You can't assign using `=` in *either* direction, because it's a many-to-many, but you can do `my_product.categories.add(some_category)` and `my_category.product_set.add(some_product)`. All this is of course [fully documented](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/models/relations/). If you have any other problems you should ask a new question.

Comment: @DanielRoseman and that was the thing i was looking for, thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

### Mar, 2022 Update:

There are 2 ways to create **"many-to-many" relationship** in **Django**. One doesn't use **"ManyToManyField()"** and one uses **"ManyToManyField()"**. First of all, I'll show you the way which doesn't use **"ManyToManyField()"**.

#### <The way without "ManyToManyField()">

To create **many-to-many relationship**, there must be **the middle table between 2 other tables** and it must have **each foreign key from 2 other tables** and **these foreign keys must be unique together**. So, I created **the middle table "CategoryProduct" between "Category" and "Product" tables** and it has **each foreign key from "Category" and "Product" tables** and **these foreign keys are unique together** as shown below.

**"models.py"**:

```py
from django.db import models

class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)    
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

# The middle table between "Category" and "Product" tables
class CategoryProduct(models.Model): 
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = [['category', 'product']]
```

And this is how you inline **the middle table "CategoryProduct"** to **"Product" table** as shown below.

**"admin.py"**:

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import CategoryProduct, Product

class CategoryProductInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = CategoryProduct
    min_num = 1 
    extra = 2
    max_num = 5

@admin.register(Product)
class ProductAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [CategoryProductInline]
```

This is how it looks like:

[image]

And this is how you inline **the middle table "CategoryProduct"** to **"Category" table** as shown below.

**"admin.py"**:

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import CategoryProduct, Category

class CategoryProductInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = CategoryProduct
    min_num = 1 # 1 required inline field displayed
    extra = 2   # 2 unrequired inline fields displayed
    max_num = 5 # 5 inline fields as a maximum

@admin.register(Category)
class CategoryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [CategoryProductInline]
```

This is how it looks like:

[image]

#### <The way with "ManyToManyField()">

This is the way with **"ManyToManyField()"** as shown below. The difference between the way with **"ManyToManyField()"** and the way without **"ManyToManyField()"** above is in this case of the way with **"ManyToManyField()"**, **"categories" field** with **"ManyToManyField()"** is added to **"Product" class** as you can see below and there is the only code difference between them so other things are the same.

**"models.py"**:

```py
from django.db import models

class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
    
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    categories = models.ManyToManyField(
        Category, 
        through='CategoryProduct'
    ) # "categories" field is added

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class CategoryProduct(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = [['category', 'product']]
```

And you can add **"products" field** with **"ManyToManyField()"** to **"Category" class** and there is only code difference as well so other things are the same as well.

**"models.py"**:

```py
from django.db import models

class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    products = models.ManyToManyField(
        Product, 
        through='CategoryProduct'
    ) # "products" field is added

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class CategoryProduct(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = [['category', 'product']]
```

So, how you inline **the middle table "CategoryProduct"** to **"Product" table** is also the same as the way without **"ManyToManyField()"** as shown below.

**"admin.py"**:

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import CategoryProduct, Product

class CategoryProductInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = CategoryProduct
    min_num = 1 
    extra = 2
    max_num = 5

@admin.register(Product)
class ProductAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [CategoryProductInline]
```

This is how it looks like:

[image]

And, how you inline **the middle table "CategoryProduct"** to **"Category" table** is the same as the way without **"ManyToManyField()"** as shown below.

**"admin.py"**:

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import CategoryProduct, Category

class CategoryProductInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = CategoryProduct
    min_num = 1 # 1 required inline field displayed
    extra = 2   # 2 unrequired inline fields displayed
    max_num = 5 # 5 inline fields as a maximum

@admin.register(Category)
class CategoryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [CategoryProductInline]
```

This is how it looks like:

[image]

In addition, when you use **"ManyToManyField()"**, you can remove **the code for the middle table "CategoryProduct" which is customizable**. In this case you remove **the code for the middle table "CategoryProduct"**, **the default middle table which is not customizable is created implicitly**. So, I removed **the code for the middle table "CategoryProduct"** and **"through='CategoryProduct'"** from **"ManyToManyField()"** as shown below.

**"models.py"**:

```py
from django.db import models

class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    categories = models.ManyToManyField(Category)
    categories = models.ManyToManyField(
        Category, 
        # through='CategoryProduct'
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

# class CategoryProduct(models.Model):
#     category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
#     product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

#     class Meta:
#         unique_together = [['category', 'product']]
```

And by only registering **"Product"** as shown below, you can create **the form of "Product" table with the inline of the default middle table**.

**"admin.py"**:

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Product

admin.site.register(Product)
```

This is how it looks like. As you can see, **the UI(User Interface) of "Categories"** is different from when having **the custom middle table "CategoryProduct"**. For me, the UI of when having **the custom middle table "CategoryProduct"** is better:

[image]

And even if you register **"Category" table** as shown below.

**"admin.py"**:

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Category

admin.site.register(Category)
```

**The default middle table is not inlined to "Category" table** as shown below:

[image]

**To inline the default middle table to "Category" table**, **"Category" table** must have **ManyToManyField()** as shown below.

**"models.py"**:

```py
from django.db import models

class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    products = models.ManyToManyField( # Here
        Product, 
        # through='CategoryProduct'
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

# class CategoryProduct(models.Model):
#     category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
#     product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

#     class Meta:
#         unique_together = [['category', 'product']]
```

Then, by only registering **"Category"** as shown below, you can create **the form of "Category" table with the inline of the default middle table**.

**"admin.py"**:

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Category

admin.site.register(Category)
```

This is how it looks like:

[image]

This is how you create **"many-to-many" relationship** in **Django**.